# TypeError from data gathering

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, tuples

So I am trying to get this output

```
No Column Sum
0 Company 28
1 Booth 28
2 Full-Time 25
3 Full-Time Visa Sponsor 5
4 Part-Time 1
5 Internship 18
6 Freshman 7
7 Sophomore 9
8 Junior 17
9 Senior 24
10 Post-Bacs 17
11 MS 17
12 PhD 6
13 Alumni 15
```

However, I am getting this error

*TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str*

My code is the following

```
data_employer = {'No': ('Column', 'Sum')}
for vari in range(14):
    sum = 0
    for row in ReadyColumn:
        if row[vari] != '':
            sum =+1
        data_employer = (companies[vari], sum)
for num in data_employer:
    print(num, data_employer [num][0], data_employer[num][1])
outData = []
```

Is it because I need to not call num but the row number? I thought it could work this way though. Any input would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Prj3Assignt3.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(num, data_employer[num][0], data_employer[num][1])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Added with error

```
import csv
filename = "CFSpring2018Employers.csv"                         #I assigned the file to a variable
f = open(filename)                        #I couldn't leave it default due to UTF-8 error from orginial
reader = csv.reader(f)
f.close

#Dictionary for part 1 'Companies'
companies = {}
countComp = 0 #Sets the 'rows to 0

for row in reader: #reader has assigned value to read csv info
    if row[0] == 'Company': #Searches row called 'Company'
        for item in row:
            companies[countComp] = item #Everytime it shows it puts it into the dictionary
            countComp += 1
        break

for i in companies: #Allows me to print numbers next to the companies dict
    print(i, companies[i])

ReadyColumn = []    #Making a new list for cleaned up data
NumCow = 0
for row in reader:
    NumCow +=1
    if NumCow > 0 and NumCow < 31 and row[0] != '': #This will read the rows between 0-31, and if the row contains 'Nothing' it skips
        ReadyColumn.append(row) #Updates the list
rowNum = -1 #Resets the counter

for row in ReadyColumn:
    rowNum += 1
    print(rowNum, ','.join(row)) #Joins any weird marks and prints as desired output

data_employer = {'No', 'Column', 'Sum'}
for vari in range(14):
    sum = 0
    for row in ReadyColumn:
        if row[vari] != '':
            sum =+1
        cleaner_employer = (companies[vari], sum)
for i in data_employer:
    print(i, data_employer,i[0], data_employer,i[1])
```

So this is the code I wrote to help get to this point. I am reading a csv file without **PANDAS** (because I can't use them for the project)

Comment: Please post the snippet of the actual error as printed in full stack trace.

Comment: Ok updated with error

Answer (score 1):

You redefine `data_employer` in the middle of your function to a tuple: `data_employer = (companies[vari], sum)`. Use another name to avoid this.

In the following code:

```
for num in data_employer:
    print(num, data_employer [num][0], data_employer[num][1])
```

num will first be `companies[vari]`, then `sum`. `companies[vari]` is probably a string. Tuple can only be access with integer. dict can by access with a key (any hashable object).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** You are overwriting your variable name and changing its data type.

You've overwritten your dictionary with a tuple! Lets take a look...

First, your code in full with comments:

```
data_employer = {'No': ('Column', 'Sum')} # original dictionary
for vari in range(14):
    sum = 0
    for row in ReadyColumn: # no idea what ReadyColumn is...post this?
        if row[vari] != '':
            sum =+1
        data_employer = (companies[vari], sum) # the issue occurs here!!!
for num in data_employer:
    print(num, data_employer [num][0], data_employer[num][1]) # where you get TypeError
outData = []
```

Obviously there is code omitted (showing `ReadyColumn` and `companies`; both of which appear to be iterables of some form); but we can still address the problem either way.

At the start, you declare and define a dictionary, with the name `data_employer`:

```
data_employer = {'No': ('Column', 'Sum')}
```

In your loop however, you eventually replace that name with a tuple!

```
data_employer = (companies[vari], sum)
```

Think of it like this:

```
>>> data_employer = {'No': ('Column', 'Sum')}
>>> isinstance(data_employer, dict)
True
>>> data_employer = (companies[vari], sum)
>>> isinstance(data_employer, dict)
False
>>> isinstance(data_employer, tuple)
True
```

When you try to access it by `[num]`, its already changed from key access (like dictionaries are normally), to index access (like tuples are normally).

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your input. You explain it very well, I have updated with the rest of the code cause I saw your comment. I see what your saying by changing my dictionary into a tuple.

Comment: @PKPython Read up on the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) for more information!